# FormData append not working, its showing empty object

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to convert data into formdata. As you can see here upto input of `onSubmit`, the data is showing fine, But, I tried it to append as formData, but its not working.

```
const onSubmit = async (input) => {
    console.log("input >>", input);
    const formData = formHelper.getFormData(input);
    console.log("formData >>", formData);
    // submitAction(formData, setError);
};
```

formHelper.js

```
const getFormData = (object) =>
    Object.keys(object).reduce((formData, key) => {
        if (object[key] instanceof File) {
            formData.append(key, object[key][0]);
        } else {
            formData.append(key, object[key]);
        }
        return formData;
    }, new FormData());


const formHelper = {
    getFormData,
};

export default formHelper;
```

And, here is the screenshot of the console.log.
[image]

Answer (score 3):

When logging a `formData` object with just `console.log(formData)` it always returns empty, as you can't log `formData`. If you just have to log it before sending it, you can use `entries()` to get the entries in the `formData` object, like this:

```
 for (var key of formData.entries()) {
      console.log(key[0] + ", " + key[1]);
  }
```